# Rails verify the assets in the assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I wanted to verify what CSS and JS the application has added into the asset pipeline during development.

Answer (score 1):

#### CSS in the asset pipeline

To access the styles accumulated in the asset pipeline during development - enter into the browser:

```
localhost:3000/assets/application.css
```

#### JS in the asset pipeline

To access the scripts accumulated in the asset pipeline during development - enter into the browser:

```
localhost:3000/assets/application.js
```

#### Reference

[Railscasts #279 - Understanding the Asset Pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline?autoplay=true)